# Wiring E27 lamp holder with switch

Tags: electrical

how do I wire this lamp holder? http://www.creative-cables.co.uk/33985-big_default/e27-lamp-holder-with-switch-black-bakelite.jpg I am confused by the switch.

I live in Sweden if that matters. I have a regular cable without earth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej!

Jag har sökt samma svar i ett par veckor och blev glad att se bilden du länkat till. Plötsligt slog det mig att ena ledaren kan först fästas på brytarens nedre fäste och den andra på "plattans" fäste som inte "spiken" kommer upp till. "Spiken" kan skruvas fast sist på rätt höjd eftersom det finns en öppning kvar vid det skruvfästet tills man sist skruvar ned själva lamphållarens "rör". Ja du hör ju att det inte är en elektriker som talar, men det blir faktiskt en krets med vippbrytaren som öppnar/sluter som den ska. Jag skruvade ihop den på några minuter. Ska våga prova den och återkommer!

Hälsar Ulf

Yepp, det funkade!

Ulf

[image]

In English:
One leader attached to the bottom of the switch part and the other leader attached to the part connecting to the lightbulb. The bent "nail" fixated finally to the right hight in the last hole and it can be twisted together. This makes an electric circuit, but I am NOT an electrician by far and will welcome any confirmation that this is the right and secure way to assamble this. I will check with my electric store and return shortly.

Regards Ulf

Yepp, worked like a charm!

Sorry about the Swedish and my poor explanation (in both languages). Stupid as I am I did not think of taking a photo of my first attempt of wiring and since it did turn out to work I am not dismanteling a fully operational light. However I have marked on the photograph provided by the questionaire how it's done.

[image: The switch opens and closes the electrical circle this way.]

Comment: Thank you but your answer was hard to understand. A photo of the wiring would have been helpful.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We're an English-only site, and your English explanation is very hard to understand. If this is important to you, please spend some time elaborating.

Comment: Do you mean me or Ulf @DanielGriscom ?

Comment: @user1766169 Sorry: I meant the original author. (I'm the one who up-voted your comment.)